# Compute the greatest common divisor of $ \ 300⋅35⋅7^{5}\ $ and $ \ 33^{5} ⋅3⋅64$

Tags: divisibility, euclidean-algorithm

Question:

Compute the greatest common divisor of $ \ 300⋅35⋅7^{5}\ $ and $ \ 33^{5} ⋅3⋅64$ using Euclidean algorithm.

I am not even sure which of the two numbers is bigger. Is there any way to figure that out? I need to write it in the form $ \  a = bq + r$ to start.

Comment: Do you *have* to use the Euclidean algorithm?  Given the way you received the numbers, it is easy to get the prime factorization of each, then to take the minimum power of each prime between the two numbers and be done.  You don't even have to know which is larger that way.

Comment: compare the parts with similar exponents would be a start.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  no, you want to compare the powers of each prime that divides each.

Comment: Yes I have to use Euclidean algorithm

Comment: @RossMillikan there are multiple ways to do it actually and if you can break it down into prime powers then you can cherry pick without doing the algorithm...  using 35<64 and 3<300 you can get a factor that (33/7)^5 must exceed for one to be greater.

Comment: doh you can replace it with the absolute value regardless.

Comment: The more challenging problem is how you divide the two large numbers to obtain the remainder, which you have to know if you insist to use Euclidean Algorithm. Once you know how to do that, the smaller number can be identified by division if you see a quotient of $0$ and a remainder that equals the dividend.

Answer (score 0):

To find which is larger without a calculator I would note that $\frac {33}7$ is about $5$, so the fifth power terms contribute five extra factors of $5$ on the right.  $\frac {300}{64}$ will take care of one and $\frac {35}3$ will take care of less than two, so $33^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 64 \gt 300 \cdot 35 \cdot 7^5$  Checking with Alpha gives $7513995456 \gt 176473500$.  The ratio is about $40$ instead of the $25$ I came up with in my estimate.

Comment: I need to use Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel:  this answers your question of which is larger.  You can use $a=7513995456, b=176473500$ in the Euclidean algorithm.  I don't envy you doing the division by hand if you must.  If you are allowed a calculator, you could use that to find which is larger.

Comment: I am not allowed calculators. How can I use the Euclidean algorithm along with prime factorization?

Comment: You can't.  You just need to divide $a$ by $b$ and note the quotient and remainder.  Fortunately the size of the numbers reduces fairly quickly